# How to escape a '\' in a string before casting to a bytea?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, backslash, bytea

I am trying to resolve an error that occurs when users are entering text that contains a single backslash thus throwing an error when we cast the string to a bytea.

Error logs:

```
2023-04-12 18:10:37.249  WARN 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22P02

2023-04-12 18:10:37.250 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea

2023-04-12 18:10:37.251  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

2023-04-12 18:10:37.258 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.s.api.bolt.servlet.SlackAppServlet     : Failed to handle a request - could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
```

A quick explanation, a user inputs an agenda, we encode on write and decode on read.

Some values that **do not** trigger an error (notice that these working values **do not contain a single backslash**):

```
My agenda with my boss and a peer has a few items.

Let's chat today about the weather!
```

Some values that **do not** trigger an error (notice that these working values **contain a double backslash**):

```
Let's chat with Chad\\Brad has a few items.

In today's meeting with Chad\\Brad let's chat about a few items
```

Some values that **do** trigger an error (notice that these values **contain a single backslash**):

```
Let's chat with Chad\Brad has a few items.

In today's meeting with Chad\Brad let's chat about a few items
```

My current code is:

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "convert_from(decode(agenda, 'base64'), 'UTF8')", write = "encode(?::bytea, 'base64')")
private String agenda;
```

After reading through a few stack articles, someone suggested using replace to escape the backslash before casting to a bytea.

I attempted the following:

My expectation would be the logic below is replacing a backslash with a double backslash thus preventing the error. After testing with the example values above, I ran into the exact same error as initially stated.

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "convert_from(decode(agenda, 'base64'), 'UTF8')", write = "encode(replace(?, '\', '\\')::bytea, 'base64')")
private String agenda;
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please update the question with both a working and a failing value for *agenda*. The exception is being caused by a combination of code and value and only one of those has been provided.

Comment: @JohnH Sorry about that! Thanks for the call out that I missed some pretty important information. Just added a few examples of working and failing values.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that your code environment is using the `\` as an escape character which results in `replace(?, '\', '\\')` being seen as `replace(?, '', '\')` when it's passed to PostgreSQL. Try changing  the code to `replace(?, '\\', '\\\\')`.

Comment: @JohnH That solved it!! You bring up a great point - Thanks for your speedy assistance!